# Beautifullsoup get text in tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get data from yellowpages, but i need only numbered plumbers. But i can't get text numbers in **h2 class='n'**. I can get a **class="business-name"** text but i need only numbered plumbers not with advertisement. What is my mistake? Thank you very much.

This html :

```
<div class="info">
   <h2 class="n">1.&nbsp;<a class="business-name" href="/austin-tx/mip/johnny-rooter-11404675?lid=171372530" rel="" data-impressed="1"><span>Johnny Rooter</span></a></h2>
</div>
```

And this is my python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/austin-tx/plumbers"
req = requests.get(url)
data = req.content
soup = bs(data, "lxml")
links = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "info"})

for link in links:
        for content in link.contents:
            try:
                print(content.find("h2", {"class": "n"}).text)
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a different class selector to limit to that section

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/austin-tx/plumbers"
req = requests.get(url)
data = req.content
soup = bs(data, "lxml")
links = [item.text.replace('\xa0','') for item in soup.select('.organic h2')]
print(links)
```

`.organic` is a single class selector, from a compound class, for a parent element which restricts to all the numbered plumbers. Observe how the highlighting starts after the ads:

[image]

---

**Output:**

[image]